# How to make background image position stay same on all resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have header (100% width, 277px height), and in `header` I should have background image, x-repeated, which will **stay in same position** (x axis position), on all resolutions (1024+ actually, no need for mobile version so far). This is how it should look on all resolutions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjGRZ.png  (see profit, and cloud line under it - that's right position)

However, by changing resolution, background image changes it's position too ...

HTML:

## Webopps

```
    <h2>Helping you profit</h2>

    <h3>from the Web</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact us</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
      </li>

      <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#">The market</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Mainstream</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">Adult</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">Niche</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Downloads</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width:100%;
    height:277px;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(images/clouds2.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:-133px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kF7Br/

Test link: http://bybyweb.com/webopps/

I have tried with media queries (not so smart solution, you can see at the bottom of my css, but without success), i have thought about js/jquery solutions, but have no idea how to make it... I am opened to all kind of hacks/solutions (css, jquery, html structure changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
function bgPos(){
    var w = $(window).width() - $('#header-content').width();
    w = w/2;
    $('#header').css('background-position', w+'px 0')
}


$(window).on('resize', bgPos).trigger('resize');
```

But you will have to do some maths to place it well.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kF7Br/1/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

Also, if you dont need its position to be relative, set it to absolute.

Comment: Yes, i tried (background-attachment:fixed), no success, specific case, as you can see... content is 1000px width, image is wider... also, i have tried with adding new html elements to hold image, and position propert changing...

Answer (score 0):

For the desktop version, I suggest using the top and center keywords instead of using pixels.  This approach looked good until about 400px wide, at that width you could use a responsive media query to override to a pixel value like you had before.

```
background-position:top center;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however, because of specific image (not so nicely cropped,), i couldn't apply it... if different image is in question/differently cropped, it could be solution.

Comment: I was able to get it to work through editing the css properties in firebug, the crop of the image did not matter.  I recommend that you do not use javascript to fix a css issue unless you really need to.

Comment: background-position: top center; slightly moves image out of desired place (see imgur image link i posted), and without some additional code, i am not sure that it can be used, in this case...

Comment: if you slightly change your html structure, you can easily position this element with simple css and the background won't jump on resize. 

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/brandonbabb/k4EBy/

to move the image to exactly where you need it, adjust these properties on #header2:

    padding-left:630px;
    margin-right:-630px;