# Horizontally fix background image to logo in header

Tags: javascript, html, css

my problem is quite simple. I need the diagonal line in the background image to align with the "X" in the logo and make it stay there no matter how wide the viewport is. I tried to achieve it with css only but with no result. It´s gonna need some javascript I suppose but I have no idea where to start.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <svg class="logo"></svg>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: url(http://mujtest.tk/ci/site/templates/img/hero2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

header { 
  opacity: 1;
  height: 135px;
  line-height:135px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  line-height: 135px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 80px;  
}

.logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/easynowbaby/pen/qdLbgP

Thanks!

Comment: Had similar problem... maybe solution could help to you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618369/how-to-make-background-image-position-stay-same-on-all-resolutions

Comment: Is it not an option to use position: absolute on the bg and the logo?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOvGKv?editors=110

Comment: A nice solution would be to add the logo to the background image in Photoshop or another editing tool. Unless ofcourse, you want to be able to click the logo?

Answer (score 0):

looks like what you want is to play around with the background position, try something like this,

```
background: url(http://mujtest.tk/ci/site/templates/img/hero2.jpg) no-repeat center -110px;
```